# Angles between two geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I've just started differential geometry with do carmo textbook.
I get to geodesic concept and its properties and can't understand a simple fact.
Why the external angle between two geodesic can't achieve $\pi$ value or equivalently at a corner with two geodesic segment the external angle $|\theta| < \pi$ and $\theta \neq\pi$? My question is why this external angle can't be exactly $\pi$.
(External angle means the angles between their tangent line)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Something is wrong with the definition that you wrote. Please, provide the exact definition copied from the textbook.

Comment: I assume that you are reading do Carmo's book "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces." The relevant definition is on page 266 and he absolutely allows the case of external angles $\pm \pi$ ("cuspidal curves"). In fact, he has a rather extensive discussion of how to assign the $\pm$ sign in this case. The question which you actually should have asked is "does do Carmo allow zero external angles": This is where he is sloppy. At first he does not, but then he does. There are other issues with do Carmo's treatment of Gauss-Bonnet theorem, but the angle $\pm\pi$ is not one of these.

Comment: Indeed, My issue is external angle in geodesics. Two geodesics can't have external angle $pi$ or mutually tangent. later in Gauss-Bonnet theorem he mention it. I want to know the reason of this.

Comment: Why do you say that "two geodesics can't have external angle $\pi$"? This simply false. Consider the Cartesian plane with the standard Euclidean metric. Take the geodesic segment $\gamma_1$ equal to $[(0,0), (1,0)]$ (oriented from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$) and the geodesic segment $\gamma_2$ equal to $[(1,0), (0,0)]$ (oriented from $(1,0)$ to $(0,0)$). The external angle between these segments will be $\pm\pi$.

Comment: Actually, there is an exception that two geodesics has external angle $\pi$ should equivalent but I mean if two geodesic has distinct point then this couldn't occur.